# How to make a column in report with names of all columns that are checked?

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2013

I have an Access data table with 10 columns with basis of complain(bullying, harassment, etc.) that are yes or no type. In a report I want all the columns that were clicked as yes. Obviously I do not want all the columns to be on the report and a check mark if it applies to the record. I want to create another column name called basis and in this the column names of all basis columns that are clicked as yes separated by a comma Eg: Sexual Harassment, Race Discrimination,...
Any idea how I should proceed to get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table named [Complaints]...

```
Accused        Bullying  Harassment
-------------  --------  ----------
Doe, John      True      False     
Smith, Jane    False     True      
Muntz, Nelson  True      True
```

...then you can use the following query to list their alleged transgressions:

```sql
SELECT
    Accused,
    Trim(
        IIf(Bullying, "Bullying", "")
            & " " & IIf(Harassment, "Harassment", "")
    ) AS ComplaintList
FROM Complaints
```

...returning

```
Accused        ComplaintList      
-------------  -------------------
Doe, John      Bullying           
Smith, Jane    Harassment         
Muntz, Nelson  Bullying Harassment
```